# CakePHP AMFPHP 2.1 vendor integration

Tags: cakephp, amfphp

I have problem with cakephp and amfphp 2.1 integration.
I made following controller:

```
    class AmfController extends AppController
    {
        public function index(){
            App::import('Vendor','Amfphp/index');
            $this->autoRender = false;
        }
        public function backOffice(){
            App::import('Vendor', 'backOffice', array('file' => 'BackOffice' . DS . 'ServiceBrowser.php'));
            $this->autoRender = false;

        }
  }
```

Method index is working perfectly, cakephp is outputting amf entry point, but method backOffice is outputting following error:

> Service call failed

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        [maximum depth reached]
    )
    data => array([maximum depth reached])
    query => array([maximum depth reached])
    url => 'amf/backOffice'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/amf/backOffice'
}
object(CakeResponse) {

}
```

Please help me, folder Amfphp and BackOffice are located in app/Vendor folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought that might help: the service browser calls the entry point to get information about the various services, so that might create some bizarre side effects in CakePHP resulting in an infinite loop. 
Other than that I don't know... If you still have trouble post back and I will give it a try.